# Add prefix to all img src in a array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So im working on this problem to append a prefix to img src attribute

**for example**

```
<img alt='' src='/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>

to

<img alt='' src='**myprefix**/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>
```

The problem is the string in array format like this

```
[
    "<img alt='' src='/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>"
    "<img alt='' src='/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>"
    "<img alt='' src='images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>"
    "<img alt='' src='/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>"
    "<img alt='' src='/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>"

]
```

Right now i have a small working example to get the image src, but not sure how to prefix **src** attribute  in an array

```
var string ="<img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>";

var elem= document.createElement("div");
elem.innerHTML = string;

var images = elem.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0; i < images.length; i++){
   console.log(images[i].src);   
}
```

I'm a absolute beginner in JavaScript so any guidance will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you meant by prefix src atttr?!

Comment: Apologies for the typo in the above array i need to append "http://api.com/" to the already exsisting src="/images/UID" ,so that i have src="http://api.com/images/UID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable containing the prefix and use it in the `src` attribute:

```js
const prefix = 'http://api.com';
const images = [
    `<img alt="" src="${prefix}/images/UID" /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`,
    `<img alt="" src="${prefix}/images/UID" /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`,
    `<img alt="" src="${prefix}/images/UID" /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`,
    `<img alt="" src="${prefix}/images/UID" /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`,
    `<img alt="" src="${prefix}/images/UID" /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`
]
images.forEach(image => console.log(image));
```

If you're not able to modify the creation of the array you can replace the source in the strings

```js
const prefix = 'http://api.com';
const images = [
    `<img alt="" src="/images/UID" /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`,
    `<img alt="" src="/images/UID" /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`,
    `<img alt="" src="/images/UID" /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`,
    `<img alt="" src="/images/UID" /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`,
    `<img alt="" src="/images/UID" /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`
].map(image => image.replace(/src="/g, 'src="' + prefix));
images.forEach(image => console.log(image));
```

An example with multiple `img` tag:

```js
const prefix = 'http://api.com';
[
    "<hr style=\"height: 10px; background-color: #99ccff;\" />\r\n<h3>Plain text:</h3>\r\n<p>Plain text \"Plain text\", Plain text&nbsp;</p>\r\n<p><img src=\"sampleimage\" alt=\"image text\" width=\"747\" height=\"43\" /></p>\r\n<hr />\r\n<h3>plaintext:</h3>\r\n<p>blah blah blah</p>\r\n<hr />\r\n<h3>res:</h3>\r\n<p>blah blah blah:</p>\r\n<ol>\r\n<li>blah<strong>plain text</strong> plain text <strong>blah blah</strong>blah blah<br /><strong><span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">Note</span></strong>:blah blah<strong>File</strong> &gt; <strong>settings</strong> &gt; <strong>plain text</strong> &gt;&nbsp;<strong>blah</strong> &gt; <strong>plain text</strong> &gt; <strong>plain </strong><br /><br /><img src=\"/sampleimage\" alt=\"image text\" width=\"716\" height=\"126\" /><br /><br /></li>\r\n<li>blah<br /><br /><img src=\"/sampleimage\" alt=\"image text\" width=\"128\" height=\"95\" /><br /><br /></li>\r\n<li>blah blah<br /><br /><img src=\"/sample image\" alt=\"image text\" width=\"620\" height=\"33\" /></li>\r\n</ol>\r\n<hr style=\"height: 10px; background-color: #99ccff;\" />"
].map(image => image.replace(/src="/g, 'src="' + prefix)).forEach(image => console.log(image));
```

Comment: That worked and what i was looking for exactly ,Thank you +1

Comment: just one more question what if there are multiple img tags like below ,it will stop at the first img tag if there are multiple img tags in the same row,How do i tackle that ?

Comment: const images = [
    `<img alt="" src="/images/UID" /><br/>Some plain text<br/><img alt="" src="/images/UID" /><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`,
    `<img alt="" src="/images/UID" /><br/>Some plain text<br/><img alt="" src="/images/UID" /><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`,
   
]

Comment: @BHL I think the behavior of the first code is obvious: If you add `prefix` the URLs are prefixed and if you don't add `prefix` the URLs aren't prefixed. The second code prefixes all `src` attributes.

Comment: got it im using the second code to prefixall the src attributes in a sample array provided above in the question and its stopping at the first <img> src .please see the EDIT. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong here ,The above array contains some escaped chars and inline styles with HTML tags

Comment: @BHL I fixed it. [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) replaces only the first ocurrence if the first parameter is a string. I changed it to a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

This will first create the HTML elements, then go through and modify them. I wasn't sure if the OP needed to cycle through existing elements or arrays

```js
const imgs = [
  "<img alt='' src='/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>",
  "<img alt='' src='/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>",
  "<img alt='' src='images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>",
  "<img alt='' src='/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>",
  "<img alt='' src='/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>"
]

// create the elements
imgs.forEach(tag => {
  document.getElementById('tags').innerHTML += "<div>" + tag + "</div>";
});

// modify the HTML elements
let images = document.getElementById('tags').getElementsByTagName("img");
for (img of images) {
  img.src = "**myprefix**" + img.src
}
```

```html
<div id='tags'></div>
```